# Magento - PayPal express checkout button missing in Shopping cart

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart, paypal-express

Anyone else getting **PayPal express** checkout button in shopping cart missing?

[image]

From older posts It looks like It might be from the server being down?

Anyway, when I got to : `fpdbs.paypal.com` I can't reach the website.

The button image source is : https://fpdbs.paypal.com/dynamicimageweb?cmd=_dynamic-image&buttontype=ecshortcut&locale=en_GB&ordertotal=#####&pal=########

And that fails too.

Anyone else?

Answer (score 0):

Just for anyone else to know in the future.
It was that the server was down.
Has fixed itself.